# Recursive function calls in python in list comprehension gives different result than assigning the result of the call to a variable first

Tags: python

Why doesn't this:

```
def subsets(x):
    if not x:
        return [[]]
    else:
        return [x + y for x in [[], [x[0]]] for y in subsets(x[1:])]

print subsets(['a', 'b'])
```

produce the same output as this:

```
def subsets(x):
    if not x:
        return [[]]
    else:
        z = subsets(x[1:])
        return [x + y for x in [[], [x[0]]] for y in z]

print subsets(['a', 'b'])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the name `x` for two different things. When you introduce `x` as a variable inside a list comprehension it hides the `x` that was defined in the function. As a result, the final `x` in your list comprehension isn't refering to the  `x` that you had hoped for.

Renaming one of the `x` to something else fixes the problem:

```
def subsets(original_x):
    if not original_x:
        return [[]]
    else:
        return [x + y for x in [[], [original_x[0]]]
                      for y in subsets(original_x[1:])]
```

I would also suggest that you try to find more descriptive names for your variables. This will reduce the likelihood of accidentally reusing a name.

Comment: +1 - It's easy to overlook this kind of thing in list comprehensions, when you think of the individual parts as separate, and I completely agree on better names - it makes this type of error less likely, and more obvious when it happens.